# Android studio Gradle dependency library download url

Tags: android, gradle

I develop android applications via Android Studio. And I would like to use 3 party libraries but I am working in a safe network which blocks all the internet except few which are specified by IT admin. I do NOT want to work with offline gradle option (Settings -> Gradle -> offline work). I would like to use gradle as if I got internet. To do that I need know which url is required, and tell IT admin open this spesific url.
My question is which link or links I require ?

EDIT:

```
 http://jcenter.bintray.com/
```

link above is accepted answer but also links below are required for gradle

```
 http://download.gradle.com
 http://services.gradle.com

 http://repo.jfrog.org
```

Comment: depends on the repo you use - e.g. jcenter or mavenCentral

Comment: I am using both jcenter and mavenCentral.

Comment: both is kind of not useful as jcenter is a superset of maven-central

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This depends on the repositories on which your 3'rd party libraries are hosted.
The standard ones probably include Maven Central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2) and JCenter (https://jcenter.bintray.com or http://jcenter.bintray.com/), and if you also use private repositories defined by a url (see example below) then you should include these as well.

Example for a private maven repository definition, taken from [Gradle User Guide](https://gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/dependency_management.html#sec:repositories):

> ```
> repositories {
>     maven {
>         url "http://repo.mycompany.com/maven2"
>     }
> }
> ```

One last note - Maven Central and JCenter urls mentioned above are taken from [Gradle User Guide](https://gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/dependency_management.html#sec:repositories).

Comment: I just need to know standart ones, thank you. I will try those urls.

Comment: @Amnon what for android support libraries... like for com.android.support:design:25.3.1

Answer (score 0):

I think u have to include the android studio in whitelist... whitelist means, there should have certain apps in your system which are allowed to visit all links...